# RxJS: Combining historical data with a stream of updates

Tags: javascript, rxjs

### Scenario:

I'm loading an initial array of data via a simple ajax call and putting that data through and Observable, which I'll call **historical**. In parallel, I connect to a websocket and periodically receive data, which we'll call **updates**, and I want to append this data to **historical**.

Concretely, let's say the ajax call sends back the array `[0,1,2]` and the socket emits (over time) `3`, `4`, `5` then I want to accumulate these values like so:

```js
[0,1,2]        // historical
[0,1,2,3]      // historical + updates1
[0,1,2,3,4]    // historical + updates1 + updates2
[0,1,2,3,4,5]  // etc
```

(Note that there's a concurrency edge case here that has to be handled: It could happen that **historical** yields `[0,1,2,3]` and the first two of the **updates** are `3` and `4`, in which case what I want to end up with is still `[0,1,2,3,4]` — **NOT** `[0,1,2,3,3,4]`.)

The end goal is to end up with a single Observable **stream**, which is the combination of the Observables **historical** and **updates** as described.

### What I've tried so far:

Accumulating just the websocket data is easy enough. I create **updates**, which is the Observable sequence emitted by the websocket. Each time a value is observed, I can accumulate it into array, using `scan()`:

```js
updates.scan((acc, update) => acc.concat([update]), [])
```

This would yield something like

```js
[3]
[3,4]
[3,4,5]
```

My next issue was how to combine it with **historical**. And since **historical**'s data might arrive after one or more **updates** were already observed, those updates need to be accumulated while we wait for **historical**. I managed to achieve this using `withLatestFrom()`:

```js
const stream = historical
  .withLatestFrom(
    updates.scan((acc, update) => acc.concat([update]), []),
    (history, buffer) => history.concat(buffer) /* could eliminate duplicates here */
  )
```

Observing **stream** yields a single value, `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` which is the combination of **historical** and any **updates** that arrived before **historical**. Just what I wanted.

However, I can't figure out where to go from there. How can I continue to append **updates** to **stream** so that, over time, **stream** yields something like:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5]
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

I don't see a way to use `scan` for this, the way I did for **updates**, because in this case I need `scan`'s initial (seed) value to be an Observable, not an Array.

Is there a way to do that — either by adding to what I have so far or an even better alternate way to do the whole thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly I'd use [`skipUntil()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-skipUntil) operator to keep collecting the updates without emitting them further. Then for `withLatestFrom()` operator I'd choose the `updates` Observable as its source instead. This'll wait thanks to `skipUntil()` until the historical data is available and then emit on every emission from `updates`.

```
let updates = Observable
  .timer(0, 1000)
  .scan((acc, update) => {
    acc.push(update);
    return acc;
  }, []);

let historical = Observable.defer(() => { 
    console.log('Sending AJAX request ...');
    return Observable.of(['h1', 'h2', 'h3']); 
  })
  .delay(3000)
  .share();


const stream = updates.skipUntil(historical)
  .withLatestFrom(historical, (buffer, history) => {
    return history.concat(buffer);
  })
  .map(val => val) // remove duplicates;


stream.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Output in console is the following:

```
Sending AJAX request ...
["h1", "h2", "h3", 0, 1, 2, 3]
["h1", "h2", "h3", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
["h1", "h2", "h3", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/kumolez/11/edit?js,console

I don't know what you're usecase is but I'd try to avoid using `concat()` because it might get slow when the `buffer` grows.

Also, if you were emitting the updates as they arrive one item at the time (instead of accumulating them) you could use `distinct()` operator to filter out duplicates.

Btw, I'm assuming you're using RxJS 5.

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate answer! I still haven't fully wrapped my head around FRP, so I learned a bunch from your example. My use case is a simple intraday stock chart. On load, it requests and renders the price graph for the day so far (`historical`) and keeps refreshing the chart as new price data arrives via socket over time (`updates`). `stream` serves as the accumulator of the data to be rendered. I too am concerned about the `history.concat(buffer)` step, which gets executed on each update whereas it really only needs to happen once, when the ajax response arrives. Still a good answer.